# Keras LSTM neural network for Time Series Predictions shows nan during model fit

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, time-series, lstm

I am training a neural network to predict a whole day of availability (144 samples, 6 features) by passing yesterday's availability (144 samples). I'm having trouble finding good resources or explanations on how to define a neural network to predict time series in a regression problem. The training is defined as a supervised learning problem. My definition of the neural network is,

```
lstm_neurons = 30

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(lstm_neurons * 2, input_shape=(self.train_x.shape[1], sel    f.train_x.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(lstm_neurons * 2))
model.add(Dense(len_day, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics = [rm    se, 'mae', 'mape'])
```

I am training for 20 epochs with a batch size of 200 where the used datasets have the following shapes,

```
Train X (9631, 144, 6)
Train Y (9631, 144)
Test X (137, 144, 6)
Test Y (137, 144)
Validation X (3990, 144, 6)
Validation Y (3990, 144)
```

All of this produces `nan` values during training for `loss`, `rmse`, `mae`... While this looks like it's a problem I can use the generated model to generate predictions and they look good-ish.

Comment: Have you normalized your data? That may help solving your problem if not please take a look at this posts on how to normalize your data for LSTM -RNN https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43467597/should-i-normalize-my-features-before-throwing-them-into-rnn and this discussion about data normalization for LSTM-RNN https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43467597/should-i-normalize-my-features-before-throwing-them-into-rnn

Comment: It should be noted that while normalization is a key part of the process, the OP should be aware that this will still return readings - only they will be very spurious, i.e. loss readings will be very large compared to working with scaled data. So, while failing to normalize might return nan values, this might not be the case in all situations.

Answer (score 0):

The first question to ask - are you trying to predict a time series based on interpreting availability as a probability measure?

The **softmax** activation function would work best under [this scenario](https://towardsdatascience.com/choosing-the-right-hyperparameters-for-a-simple-lstm-using-keras-f8e9ed76f046) - but you may be misspecifying it when you are in fact attempting to forecast an interval time series - hence why you are obtaining NaN readings for your results.

This example might be of use to you - LSTM is used to this example to forecast weekly fluctuations in hotel cancellations.

Similarly to your example, **X_train** and **X_val** are reshaped as *samples, time steps, features*:

```
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
X_val = np.reshape(X_val, (X_val.shape[0], 1, X_val.shape[1]))
```

The LSTM network is defined as follows:

```
# Generate LSTM network
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, previous)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

As you can see, the **mean squared error** is used as the loss function since the cancellation variable in question is interval (i.e. can take on a wide range of values and is not necessarily restricted by any particular scale).

I can only speculate as I have not seen your data or results, but you may be going wrong by defining **softmax** as your activation function when it is not appropriate - I suspect this is the case as you are also using mean squared error as the loss measurement.

In the above example, the Dense layer does not specify an activation function per se.

In terms of how you might choose to validate whether your time series forecast with LSTM is effective, a potentially good idea is to compare the findings to that of a simpler time series model; e.g. ARIMA.

Using our example, ARIMA performed better when forecasting for **Hotel 1**, but LSTM performed better when forecasting for **Hotel 2**:

```
H1 Results

Reading     ARIMA   LSTM
MDA     0.86    0.8
RMSE    57.95   63.89
MFE     -12.72  -54.25

H2 Results

Reading     ARIMA   LSTM
MDA     0.86    0.8
RMSE    274.07  95.28
MFE     156.32  38.65
```

Finally, when creating your datasets using the train and validation sets, you must also ensure that you are using the correct **previous** parameter, i.e. the number of time periods going back with which you choose to regress against the observations at time *t*.

For instance, you are using yesterday's availability - but you might find that the model is improved using the previous 5 or 10 days, for instance.

```
# Number of previous
previous = 5
X_train, Y_train = create_dataset(train, previous)
X_val, Y_val = create_dataset(val, previous)
```

In your situation, the first thing I would check is the use of the **softmax** activation function, and work from there.