# Why does this code use MinMaxScaler to preprocess S&P 500 index data?

Tags: scikit-learn, deep-learning, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
sp500_scaled = pd.Series(scaler.fit_transform(sp500).squeeze(), 
                         index=sp500.index)
sp500_scaled.describe()
```

This code is from the book Machine learning for algorithmic trading.

https://github.com/stefan-jansen/machine-learning-for-trading/blob/main/19_recurrent_neural_nets/01_univariate_time_series_regression.ipynb

It uses a two-layer RNN to predict S&P 500 index, which is a time series of stock market index. The overall task is a time-series prediction task. It uses data of 63 time steps to predict the next time step data. And of course after training the model, the prediction results on test set are scaled back to original size to compute the prediction loss.

Before scaling the data, it is.

```
DATE    SP500
2012-01-04  1277.30
2012-01-05  1281.06
2012-01-06  1277.81
2012-01-09  1280.70
2012-01-10  1292.08
... ...
2019-12-24  3223.38
2019-12-26  3239.91
2019-12-27  3240.02
2019-12-30  3221.29
2019-12-31  3230.78
2011 rows × 1 columns
```

After scaling it with MinMaxScaler, it is

```
DATE
2012-01-04    0.000000
2012-01-05    0.001916
2012-01-06    0.000260
2012-01-09    0.001732
2012-01-10    0.007530
                ...   
2019-12-24    0.991522
2019-12-26    0.999944
2019-12-27    1.000000
2019-12-30    0.990457
2019-12-31    0.995292
Length: 2011, dtype: float64
```

I don't know why it is necessary to use a MinMaxScaler to transform all S&P 500 data to [0,1] before feeding it into the RNN time-series prediction model.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43467597/should-i-normalize-my-features-before-throwing-them-into-rnn/43526354

Comment: basically you want to weigh your features equally and reach convergence faster

Comment: @StupidWolf Thanks. There is only one index so there are no other features. But I can understand it is for faster convergence.